# How to open a popover on the mouse click location

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have loaded an image on my HTML page and I'd like to open a popover from Twitter Bootstrap right over the mouse click position. 
What I have done so far is to open the popover on the side of the image. But what I really want to do is to open the popover wherever I've clicked on the image.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? any sample code will help others answer your problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to get the mouse coordinates and make your script use them to position the popover on click. If you're using jQuery this might help:

```
$('#yourimage').click(function(){
      $('#popover').css('left', pageX-(popover width)+'px');
      $('#popover').css('top', pageY-(popover height)+'px');
})
```

**---EDIT---**

**[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2EBGE/30/)** of what you're after.

Comment: Also, you need to set `position:absolute` to your `#popover`.

Comment: position:absolute is already set in the main bootstrap css file and need not be set again in the new styles as the position elements will only reset those mentioned in the later

Comment: I didn't have a picture of your CSS so I was just making sure you set it correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to do what you said but the popover position isn't changing. I've added it in my js file:
$('.ImgMapa').click(function(){
       $('.popover').css('left', '275px');
       $('.popover').css('top', '275px');
       $('.ImgMapa').popover('show');
 });

I used 275px just for testing.. but it doesn't work. Where can I be wrong?

Comment: can you please post the related CSS and HTML part so that I make you a demo? At a first glance, `$('.ImgMapa').popover('show');` this is not a valid function. It should be: `$('.popover').show();`

Comment: @otinanai Is there any way to position the popover dynamically? eg. In your fiddle if you click on the right most part, the popover gets cut off, in that case is it possible to show the popover towards the left?? (Is there any way to do this sort of functionality automatically)

Comment: Yeah, very close! Is there any way to do that perfectly other than using [PopperJS](https://popper.js.org) plugin?

Comment: @SE_User Having in mind the conditional statement `if (stageWidth - left < theWidth)` you can adjust the rules for every case in positioning like when scrolling, when the height doesn't fit to the window, etc. The logic is pretty simple. Try it...

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the heads up! @otinanai :)

Comment: Is it possible to make it appear below/at the bottom of the cursor?

Comment: @Gnoliz Yes it is. Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2EBGE/239/ . You just need to edit the js script (in bold) and adjust the position of the cursor:
$('.popover').css('left', **(left+20)** + 'px');   $('.popover').css('top', **(top+10)** + 'px');

Comment: @otinanai Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score -5):

Try over writing the .popover class by using the co-ordinates of your choice

```
.popover {
top: 20px !important;/*put your position */
left: 20px !important;/*put your position*/
}
```

Just resetting the position elements will keep all other styles intact in the main bootstrap.css.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I do it depending on the mouse click position? I should put this code in a .js file