# Getting top and left on Mouse click event dynamically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mouseevent, popover

My target is to get the `top` and `left` position of `cursor` when a `button` is clicked and assign it to `popover`. The purpose of doing this is to get the `popover` exactly on the position where it is clicked . Please refer https://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/2684/

```
<a id="example" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover" (click)="showCords($event)"
   data-content="This is the body of Popover"
   data-original-title="Creativity Tuts">pop
</a>
```

Here `onclick` event i am calling the `function` to get the `clientX` and `clientY`.

But nothing seems to work. I am new to `bootstrap` and just started learning, Don't even know this would work or not. Worst part is I should use only `javascript` **not `JQUERY`**.  Even the JSFiddle is a basic one only.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

**Update:**

```
  function showCords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
    document.getElementById("example").setAttribute("data-content", coords);
     document.getElementById("example").style.left="x";
     document.getElementById("example").style.top="y";
    $('#example').popover();
  }
```

Can someone tell me what is the exact mistake i am doing . I am trying to do something like this http://codepen.io/rm89/pen/aNOmzQ here my popover has to come in the position where i click in the buuton .

**Update 2:**:

[How to open a popover on the mouse click location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982224/how-to-open-a-popover-on-the-mouse-click-location) . The answer in the above link is what actly need but unfortunatelt it is in JQUERY. Can someone help me in transforming the answer to **JAVASCRIPT**

Answer (score 0):

Here you go **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/2688/)**

**first**
use `onclick` on element instead of `(click)`, **second** create javascript function like below and get top or left with `clientX` or `clientY` and if you get variable with `event` you should send it as `event` not `$event` and also if you want to show it on `popover()` you should set it on `data-content`.

```
  function showCords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
    document.getElementById("example").setAttribute("data-content", coords);
    $('#example').popover();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the resp[onse. but the popover is not getting triggered ??